# java.sql.BatchUpdateException: invalid argument(s) in call

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to insert multiple rows into Oracle table using prepared statement executebatch... I get the `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: invalid argument(s) in call` exception and my connection doesn't have a problem.. it's working in all other functions.....

I searched on the net and found invalid arguments in call only for `java.sql.SQLException` but not for `BatchUpdateException`.

Any help would be really appreciated.

---

```
public void insert(List<Employee> str, Connection con) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "insert into tbl_list(e_name,e_id) values (?,?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    for (int i = 1; i <= str.size(); i++) {
        ps.setString(1, str.get(i - 1).getName());
        ps.setString(2, str.get(i - 1).getId());
        ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
    ps.close();
    con.close();
}
```

The stacktrace is:

> May 16, 2017 2:34:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/insert] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: invalid arguments in call] with root cause java.sql.BatchUpdateException: invalid arguments in call at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10345) at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230) at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297) at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297) at dao.insert.preparedInsert(insert.java:322)

insert.java :322 is ps.executeBatch();

Comment: Well for one thing, you've said that you're going to insert five values in the row, but you're only providing two of them... what do you expect the other three to be?

Comment: str.get(i-1) but what if i==0?

Comment: changed it to two parameters as I created table with two parameters only ..edited the post accordingly....its still the same exception.....This is actually not the real code...but the original code looks like this

Comment: Can you show your `Employee` class?

Comment: both name and Id are strings if thats what u r asking

Comment: I think we need a MCVE for this.  Preferable one that really works ... and doesn't keep changing under out feet!

Comment: what's an MVCE?

Answer (score 1):

Your query contain `(?,?,?,?,?,)` **5 ?** and a typo `,` in the end, but you only set 2 parameters to your query :

```
ps.setString(1, str.get(i-1).getName());
ps.setString(2,str.get(i-1).getId());
```

Instead you have to correct your query, and like @Berger mention in comment, you have to specify the columns names in your query :

```
String sql = "insert into tbl_list(col_name1, col_name2) values (?,?)";
```

Or you have to set the correct number of your parameters.

---

You have also to use `con.setAutoCommit(false);` and `con.commit();` like this :

```
con.setAutoCommit(false); // disabling autoCommit is recommend for batching

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

for (int i = 1; i <= str.size(); i++) {
    ps.setString(1, str.get(i - 1).getName());
    ps.setString(2, str.get(i - 1).getId());
    ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();

con.commit();//commit statements to apply changes
```

Comment: what did you mean it still the same thing, can you try to show us your full error @KrishnaChaitanya

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya you ca use `try{}catch(Exception e){e.printstacktrace()}` to see the full error

Comment: good point @Berger , i totally forgot it, can i add it to my answer?

Comment: @YCF_L this is  not actually the original code...but i edited the code according to the original one.....the cloumn names are specified in the original and the value of i starts from 1 it has no problem... the point in question is why am i getting invalid arguments in call which is an sql exception for connection errors.....my connection is totally fine and tthe addBatch() command is working fine....i have a problem with executeBatch();....Also, the size of my original list is around 8000

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya what is the type of `e_id` in your table?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya did you set `con.setAutoCommit(false);` and `con.commit();` like i mention?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya you don't set `con.commit();` i can't see it in your code???, after the `ps.executeBatch()`

Answer (score 1):

Well I would recommend specifiying column names in the query `String` too, but I think you problem lies in setting the arguuments.

And more specifically the problem is with `ps.addBatch()` call, in fact you better use `Statement` and its [**.addBatch(String sql)** method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch(java.lang.String)) accepts an SQL `String` so i will take in consideration the updated SQL query in each iteration, so just make sure to pass it in `ps.addBatch(sql)`.

And why would your `for` loop start from `1` and then use
   `.get(i-1)`, if it can simply start from `0`?

Just update your code accordingly:

```
public void insert(List < Employee > str, Connection con) throws SQLException {
  String sql = "insert into tbl_list(e_name,e_id) values (?,?)";
  Statement ps = con.createStatement();

  for (int i = 0; i <= str.size(); i++) {
    ps.setString(1, str.get(i).getName());
    ps.setString(2, str.get(i).getId());
    ps.addBatch(sql); //Note the sql String here
  }
  ps.executeBatch();
  ps.close();
  con.close();
}
```

And if the problem persists with setting query arguments, why don't you just create the query in the loop itself and change it dynamically?

Here's what I suggest here:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= str.size(); i++) {
    String sql = "insert into tbl_list(e_name,e_id) values ('"+str.get(i).getName()+"','"+str.get(i).getId()+"')";
    ps.addBatch(sql);
}
```

You can take a look at [this **Batch Insert In Java – JDBC** tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/) for further reading and for full options.

Comment: ps.addBatch(sql); is giving java.sql.SQLException: unsupported feature

Comment: Have you used `Statement ps = con.createStatement();` instead of `PreparedSatement` as I recommended? You can use the code I provided in my update.

Comment: i believe that you know this can cause SQL Injection, so be careful down-voter will not understand what you mean :)

Comment: I have used oracle insert all statement which is far more better perfomance wise as i can understand from the way my code is executing....got the functionality I wanted

Comment: but I cant uderstand the inavlid arguments in call for executeBatch();  the ps.addbatch(sql) worked btw...too slow though..

Comment: @YCF_L Yes, That's why I provided the tutorial link, I just gave that suggestion for testing purposes. In the given article It clearly states that.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya I don't know maybe there was something in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Check this loop.
Here in case of i=0 it is fetching (0-1) that is -1.
As we know List provides 0 based indexing so your `str.get(..)` should start from 0 not from -1

try this

```
     public void insert(List<Employee> str, Connection con) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "insert into tbl_list values (?,?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
       for (Employee e:str) {
        ps.setString(1, e.getName());
        ps.setLong(2, e.getId());
        ps.addBatch();
       }
    ps.executeBatch();
    ps.close();
    con.close();
}
```

The stacktrace is:

`May 16, 2017 2:34:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/insert] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: invalid arguments in call] with root cause
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: invalid arguments in call
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10345)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at dao.insert.preparedInsert(insert.java:322)

insert.java :322 is ps.executeBatch();`

Comment: If your id is type of int or long take appropriate datatype like `ps.setLong(2, e.getId());`

Comment: e_id is actually a string